# Bing Maps MVVM in universal app

Tags: mvvm, bing-maps

For a long time i´ve been trying to understand the correct way of dealing with bing Maps in n MVVM scenario.

I might create a map in my XAML-view like this:

```
<map:Map x:Name="MyMap"
                 Credentials="MySuperSecretCredentials"/>
```

I the code behind file I can easily interact with map for eaxmple like this:

```
private async void FindMe_Clicked()
        {
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = _cts.Token;

            // Get the location.
            Geoposition pos = await _geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync().AsTask(token);

            MyMap.SetView(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = pos.Coordinate.Latitude, Longitude = pos.Coordinate.Longitude }, 15);

        }
```

Simply by referencing the MyMap we can do whatever we like with it in the code behind.
But how can I execute the same command my viewModel?

I guess I should start with replacing the `FindMe_Clicked` with a command calling a method on my viewModel? And have that method execute a method similar to the one in the code-behind. But How do I acess `MyMap` in the viewModel?

Maybe my VM looks like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
    {


        public RelayCommand GetLocation { get; private set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.GetLocation = new RelayCommand(this.FindMe());
        }

        public void FindMe()
        {

            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = _cts.Token;

            // Get the location.
            Geoposition pos = await _geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync().AsTask(token);

            MyMap.SetView(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = pos.Coordinate.Latitude, Longitude = pos.Coordinate.Longitude }, 15);
        }
    }
```

If im not thinking about this problem all wrong what I need to do Is to pass the same instance of `MyMap` that exists in the view to my viewmodel somehow?

Help with this is appreciated, I would also love to see any examples of how to use bibg maps i portable class libraries or i an Mvvm-pattern if anyone has come across it somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When following the MVVM pattern, you should never try to access elements of the *View* layer (e.g. the maps control) from within the Viewmodel. Instead, you'd (theoretically) create two public properties `CenterLatitude` and `CenterLongitude` and bind them to the maps control directly within XAML code:

```
<Map Credentials="MySuperSecretCredentials" ZoomLevel="15">
    <Map.Center>
        <Location Latitude="{Binding CenterLatitude}" Longitude="{Binding CenterLongitude}"/>
    </Map.Center>
</Map>
```

It's ok to have a method `FindMe` within your Viewmodel, but instead of accessing the `MyMap`control and calling `SetView(...)` from within there, you'd just update the two properties `CenterLatitude` and `CenterLongitude` and make sure that the `PropertyChanged` event is raised in order to inform the View about the changed data and to update itself.

**BUT:** Unfortunately, the bing map control's `Center` attribute does not support Data Binding - it seems that Microsoft turned this feature off intentionally for performance reasons. If you still want to keep the MVVM pattern, check out [this article I've written some time ago](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1077) that explains how to circumvent this restiction.

(In my experience, this workaround works quite well and does not affect performance. Just  make sure that you don't update the `Center` property too often, meaning several times per second...)